# How to retrieve a value from a multidimensional json array without knowing the key using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have a json file containing a multidimensional array. The first level is cities and the second is temperature data. I'm having trouble extracting the value from the second level dynamically.

I tried the following:

```
console.log(Object.values(json[0])[3][1]) but it gives me errors.
```

This works fine though:

```
console.log(Object.values(json[0])[3])
```

sample of my JSON Code below:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "city": "Amsterdam",
    "country": "Netherlands",
    "monthlyAvg": [
      {
        "high": 7,
        "low": 3,
        "dryDays": 19,
        "snowDays": 4,
        "rainfall": 68
      },
      {
        "high": 6,
        "low": 3,
        "dryDays": 13,
        "snowDays": 2,
        "rainfall": 47
      },
      {
        "high": 10,
        "low": 6,
        "dryDays": 16,
        "snowDays": 1,
        "rainfall": 65
      },
      {
        "high": 11,
        "low": 7,
        "dryDays": 12,
        "snowDays": 0,
        "rainfall": 52
      },
      {
        "high": 16,
        "low": 11,
        "dryDays": 15,
        "snowDays": 0,
        "rainfall": 59
      },
      {
        "high": 17,
        "low": 11,
        "dryDays": 14,
        "snowDays": 0,
        "rainfall": 70
      },
      {
        "high": 20,
        "low": 12,
        "dryDays": 14,
        "snowDays": 0,
        "rainfall": 74
      },
      {
        "high": 20,
        "low": 12,
        "dryDays": 15,
        "snowDays": 0,
        "rainfall": 69
      },
      {
        "high": 17,
        "low": 10,
        "dryDays": 14,
        "snowDays": 0,
        "rainfall": 64
      },
      {
        "high": 14,
        "low": 9,
        "dryDays": 16,
        "snowDays": 0,
        "rainfall": 70
      },
      {
        "high": 9,
        "low": 6,
        "dryDays": 20,
        "snowDays": 1,
        "rainfall": 82
      },
      {
        "high": 7,
        "low": 1,
        "dryDays": 19,
        "snowDays": 1,
        "rainfall": 85
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "city": "Athens",
    "country": "Greece",
    "monthlyAvg": [
```

I want to be able to retrieve the the value 7 which corresponds to high.
I can currently do this by saying:

```
json[0].monthlyAvg[0].high
```

How can I get the result without specifying ".high"

For example this is what I imagine the code to look like:
So something like this:

"high": 7 -> I want to get 7 by typing something like json[0].monthlyAvg[0][0]

"low": 3 -> I want to get 7 by typing something like json[0].monthlyAvg[0][1]

"dryDays": 19 -> I want to get 7 by typing something like json[0].monthlyAvg[0][2]

"snowDays": 4 -> I want to get 7 by typing something like json[0].monthlyAvg[3][0]

"rainfall": 68 -> I want to get 7 by typing something like json[0].monthlyAvg[0][4]

Comment: So you want to get the value of `high` by the value of `7`?

Comment: Yep - so something along the lines of json[0].monthlyAvg[0][0] <- this is incorrect, but I want to get the value without specifying the actual name (high) so that I Can put it through a loop

Comment: Ok, so you're basically trying to search your objects for any property which the value is 7?

Comment: not really - I'm just using the value 7 as an example. So something like this:
"high": 7   -> I want to get 7 by typing something like json[0].monthlyAvg[0][0]

"low": 3 -> I want to get 7 by typing something like json[0].monthlyAvg[0][1]

"dryDays": 19 -> I want to get 7 by typing something like json[0].monthlyAvg[0][2]

 "snowDays": 4 -> I want to get 7 by typing something like json[0].monthlyAvg[3][0]

 "rainfall": 68 -> I want to get 7 by typing something like json[0].monthlyAvg[0][4]

Comment: Can you update your question with the complete JSON? At least just complete the structure that's there. It'll make it easier to provide an example

Comment: its a huge table haha :) I put in more info to show the structure

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Object.values(Object.values(json[0])[3][0])
```

Now you can select high, low, dry etc with 0, 1, 2, 3,4.

Example

```
Object.values(Object.values(json[0])[3][0])[0]
```

Will return 7 (from monthlyAvg high of Amsterdam)

Explanation

```
let flattenedJson = Object.values(json[0]);
```

This returns the values in an array as you said. However, the thrid index is still an object.

```
let monthlyAVG = flattenedJson[3][n];
```

Where n is the index of the data you want to choose. This will return the object with the keys high, low, dryDays etc.

```
let flattenedData = Object.values(monthlyAVG);
```

Now we have flattened the previous object to any array.

```
let high = flattenedData[0]
```

This is how it works. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Could you explain how the structure of it works - or maybe if there is a link you can share that would have some info?

Comment: `Object.values` returns the values in some order, but not necessarily the order they appeared in the JSON, meaning this will give you a random value from Amsterdam at best and an error at worst (when `Object.values(json[0])[3]` is something other than `monthlyAvg`, since `3` is just an arbitrary entry not the fourth one in the JSON).

Comment: @Paulpro https://www.stefanjudis.com/today-i-learned/property-order-is-predictable-in-javascript-objects-since-es2015/

Comment: Thanks @PalashSharma
If I wanted to get the key instead, would it be the following:

Object.keys(Object.keys(json[0])[3][0])[0]) ?

Comment: That's an out-of-date article from before `Object.values` even existed. It is about a single version of EcmaScript (ES6), but ES7 got rid of the defined ordering for `Object.keys` and ES8 also does not have it. No version has ever had a defined order for `Object.values`.

Comment: Hi @Paulpro what is the best way to deal with this?

Comment: To get the keys, use `Object.keys(Object.values(json[0])[3][0])` However, I do not understand why you wouldn't just use the object keys to avoid confusion.

Comment: thanks! I'm populating a table and I want to run a loop to print the values high to rainfall. Is there a better way to do so using the object keys?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are approaching the problem the wrong way as there are more conveninet ways of iterating over arrays.
Have a look at this code, you can find a working example here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-grothendieck-2rjze

```
jsonData.forEach(cityObject => {
  console.log(
    `*** Printing data for ${cityObject.city}, ${cityObject.country} ***`
  );

  cityObject.monthlyAvg.forEach(avg => {
    let stringStat = "";

    for (const key in avg) {
      let value = avg[key];

      if (stringStat.length > 0) stringStat += ", ";

      stringStat += `${key}: ${value}`;
    }

    console.log(stringStat);
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks Renato, I'm currently creating a table and filtering it by a dropdown. Is there a way to just display the values from my dropdown instead?

Comment: what are the options in the dropdown?